# Change if statement with UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Hi I'm currently developing an app where you have a viewController with a UISwitch that i have got working with NSLog. My question is if you can change stuff in other viewControllers by creating a BOOL and then referring to that in the if statement? Heres some code:

```
UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(251, 111, 0, 0)];
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[mySwitch setOnTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xac1f2d)];
[self.view addSubview:mySwitch];


- (void)changeSwitch:(id)sender{

if([sender isOn]){
    NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
} else{
    NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change stuff in other view controllers and then referring to that in the if statement?"

Comment: I get the switch bit, but what is this other view controller? what does it want to change? why?

Comment: For example i have a ViewController with a UITableView in it. In this tableView i have animated the cells with core.animations. What i want to do is in the cellForRowAtIndexPath were you configure the cell is to have an if and else statement that says if the BOOL is yes then it animates if else nothing animates. And then the UISwitch would control the BOOL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change something in another ViewController, you can do this by creating a reference to the other ViewController. 
If you add public properties to the 'other' ViewController, you can change them in your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting your question to be asking whether you can change the state of another view controller using a switch on your existing view controller. The answer is yes.

You have a conditional to decide the state of the switch already. To make the connection you want to add a property to the view controller you are about to push. When you instantiate the new view controller, set the state of its property after checking `if([mySwitch isOn])` (create an IBOutlet so you can check it at any time rather than responding to an IBAction), then push it. If you're going to get there via segue, you would check the state of the switch in `prepareForSegue:` instead.

Here's how you set the property in `prepareForSegue:`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"uniqueSegueIdentifierFromIB"])
    {
        // Get a reference to the DestinationViewController
        DestinationViewController *destinationVC = [segue destinationViewController];

        // DestinationViewController has public @property (nonatomic) BOOL configurationOption;
        if([mySwitch isOn])
        {
            [destinationVC setConfigurationOption:YES];
        } 
        else 
        {
            [destinationVC setConfigurationOption:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

Check the state of the new view controller's property in `viewDidLoad:` to decide how you want to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have another VC, `OtherViewController`. 
Create a BOOL property in it like:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL flag;
```

Implement the setter for the property in .m file of `OtherViewController`:

```
-(void)setFlag:(BOOL)flag {
    _flag = flag;
    if(_flag) { //if flag is true do something
        //...........
    }
    else { //do anything else
        //........
    }
}
```

Now create a reference of `OtherViewController` instance in your first view controller, containing the switch. Say its referred by a property named `other` from the current view controller. Then you can trigger the required action on `OtherViewController` based on the switch's value from your present view controller like this:

```
- (void)changeSwitch:(UISwitch*)sender{
    self.other.flag = sender.on;
}
```

This will call the setter of `flag` property in `OtherViewController` and would according to what you have written there.

Of course, the instance of `OtherViewController` should not be deallocated in between.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Stefan [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22492392/1880431):

you would need to add `property` to the `ViewController` you want to change

so in `ViewControllerA` you would import the `ViewControllerB` header:

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"
```

So that you can change that property in the method

```
- (void)changeSwitch:(id)sender{
ViewControllerB *viewcontroller = [[ViewControllerB alloc]init]];
  if([sender isOn]){
      viewcontroller.log = @"Switch is ON";
  } else{
      viewcontroller.log = @"Switch is OFF";
  } 

 }
```

Comment: Yeah but when i import the header file i the BOOL that i have ther wont show in "ViewControllerA"

Comment: @JohanEnstam create a property BOOL in the ViewControllerB.h interface file, if you put it in the implementation you wont see it